# Where did this number come from?

Tags: php

I was reviewing some PHP code and stumbled across this:

```
if(($this->int & 0b111111111) === 0){ //blah
```

I was very puzzled at where `0b111111111` came from. What is this and how was it generated? I `var_dumped` it and it turned out to be 511, but why was this used instead of the number 511? Where did it come from?

Comment: That's binary a number, used with a bitwise operator (`&`/bitwise and) on a number that exists as a property of the class. PHP isn't a language where it's really common to work with binary, but you can do it (without seeing the application it's hard to say why it's there). Is this code for educational purposes perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an integer using [binary notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), and equals to 511 in decimal notation.

The coder is using it as mask for a binary AND (the &).

The test equals 0 only if `$this->int == 0`, as the binary AND operator compares each bit of the binary value, and returns 1 at the corresponding position where both the left and right numbers have a 1 at that position.

I have no special idea of the use here though: depending on the context, it could be for consistency. Or it's just "clever code" for writing

```
if($this->int === 0){     // Dumber blah
```

Comment: whats the purpose of it though? I mean, why not use a full round number?